# function definition in header file(c using gcc)

Tags: c, gcc

I am writing a simple c test framework. For simplicity, I only provide a single header file (containing all the function definitions), but I meet some problems. If I only include the header once, everything works fine. If I include the header twice, the gcc linker report duplicate symbol error (that is normal), so I add static prefix in every function in the header. This time it works, but the function is duplicate in the final binary. See bellow:

```
    [heidong@HEIDONGVM ztest]$ nm m | grep __ct_hex_dump
    0000000000400904 t __ct_hex_dump
    0000000000401efc t __ct_hex_dump
```

Is there some way the made the function define only once?

Thanks a lot!!

Maybe someone needs the code, I just started a project in github: https://github.com/buf1024/test

Thanks again!!

Comment: Maybe  stupid question, but do you have include guards?

Comment: This is expected behavior. If you define static function in h-file, it is added to every source file where this h-file is included. If you don't want this - move implementation to source file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I known this is the expected behavior, my question is HOW CAN I CHANGE THIS DEFAULT BEHAVIOR.

Comment: By sticking the functions in a C file instead.

Comment: @buf1024 No need to shout.

Comment: Use `nm -Cg OBJFILE | grep FUNCTION_NAME` instead. Symbols that begin with __ are implentation specific. For example static functions might be written this way but not necessarily

Answer (score 2):

What you have is in ct.h

```
static functions
static function definitions
```

In atest.c

```
// This is the first lot of definitions
#include "ct.h"
```

In main.c

```
// This is the second lot of definitions
#include "ct.h"
```

To fix

1. move the static function definitions to ct.c, remove the word static
2. Change all the prototypes in ct.h from static to extern
3. add ct.c to your link.

Edit: just delivering just ct.h

1. Change all the prototypes in ct.h from static to extern
2. Before the first function body add #ifdef __CT_C__
3. After the last function, add #endif
4. Tell the user that in the code that contains main, they need to #define __CT_C__ before they #include "ct.h"
5. Anything else that #include "ct.h" must not define __CT_C__.

Comment: thanks a lot. but suppose, if you are a libray user, you may complie you program ct.c and you files, that is not i want. I only want to deliver a single header to user, not even a library. do you have any tricky method?

Comment: You can deliver ct.h and ct.c.  Together, they aren't very big: very much less than delivering a library.  Also the user can build them on whatever system they want.  The other alternative is to play with ifdefs.  I'll outline it in the answer

Comment: Actually, user694733 has said exactly what I said so just take his/her answer since he/she got there first.

Answer (score 0):

Use compiler directives.

```
#IFNDEF MYFUNC
#DEFINE MYFUNC
myfunc();
#ENDIF
```

Everytime the compiler hits this directive, it will only go in once when MYFUNC is not defined and after defining it, it won't go in the statement again. No matter how many times you include the header file, it will always check if it's been defined before.

Coppiler directives is not part of the compiled code. It's just a directive.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely need only one file, you can do it with preprocessor:

**header.h**

```
#ifndef HEADER_H
#define HEADER_H

#ifdef IMPLEMENT
    #undef IMPLEMENT
    void func(void) {
        ...
    }
#else
    void func(void);
#endif

#endif
```

**In one file:**

```
// Define
#define IMPLEMENT
#include "header.h"
```

**In other files:**

```
// Only declarations
#include "header.h"
```

Though I would choose a proper .c file instead.